# "AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'StreamListener'" with Python 3.9

Tags: python, twitter, attributes, tweepy

```
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)  # prints every tweet received

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:  # end of monthly limit rate (500k)
            return False
```

I use Python 3.9 and installed Tweepy via pip. I get the `AttributeError` on the class line.
My import is just `import tweepy`. Authentication gets correctly handled.
In the `streaming.py` file, I have the class `Stream`. But using this class ends in that. There is for example no `status.text`, even if there is the `on_status` function. I am a little bit confused.

Comment: They didn't update the document I don't know why! I fall into the trap like you too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Tweepy v4.0.0](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/releases/tag/v4.0.0) was released recently and it merged `StreamListener` into `Stream`.

I recommend updating your code to subclass [`Stream`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.0.0/stream.html) instead.
Alternatively, you can downgrade to v3.10.0.

Comment: Yes, thanks. That was the way to go.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by @Harmon758, they merged **StreamListener** into **Stream** after version 4. Also you don`t need to create the api auth object separately. Here is the code:

```
from tweepy import Stream

class MyStreamListener(Stream):
    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)  # prints every tweet received

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:  # end of monthly limit rate (500k)
            return False


stream = MyStreamListener('consumer_key',
                          'consumer_secret',
                          'access_token',
                          'access_token_secret')

stream.filter(track=["Python"], languages=["en"])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the modules, the correct way to reference `StreamListener` is `tweepy.streaming.StreamListener`, not `tweepy.StreamListener`.